# How can I check a MongoDB collection is empty by Scala efficiently?

Tags: mongodb, scala

I want to check if a MongoDB collection is empty or not.

I know this method works:

```
if (client.getDatabase(dbName).getCollection(collectionName) == 0)
```

Using this method, I am counting the entire collection. The time it takes is costly. Is there another, more time-efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The code posted in the original question will not check if a collection is empty. It's comparing a `MongoCollection` object to an `Int`, in which case the statement will always evaluate to `false`. Recreating the logic results in the following warning message:

```
warning: comparing values of types org.mongodb.scala.MongoCollection[org.mongodb.scala.bson.collection.immutable.Document] and Int using `==' will always yield false
```

I have used the following pattern in the past, although I'm not sure if this would be the most efficient or standard approach (especially since it uses `var`, which feels taboo for Scala):

```
/* countDocuments() replaces deprecated count() in org.mongodb.scala 2.4
 * https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-scala-driver/2.4/scaladoc/org/mongodb/scala/MongoCollection.html 
 * https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-scala-driver/2.4/changelog/
 */

var isEmpty = true // your result will be stored here
var processing = true
val collection = client.getDatabase(dbName).getCollection(collectionName)
collection.countDocuments().subscribe((cnt: Long) => {
   isEmpty = (cnt == 0)
   processing = false
})
while(processing) {} // wait here until async call is completed
```